# Double pivot from one pivot column

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I've been digging around and think I've gotten most of the way to an answer. What I've got is a table that shows pay detail for employees by 'PayDate' that looks like this:

```
ID   | Name  | Dept  | RateDate  |  HrRate  |  BonusDate |  Bonus  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1   | John  |  100  | 1/1/13 R  |  10.00   |  1/1/13 B  |   200   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1   | John  |  100  | 2/1/13 R  |  10.50   |  2/1/13 B  |   220   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1   | John  |  100  | 3/1/13 R  |  11.00   |  3/1/13 B  |     0   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1   | John  |  100  | 4/1/13 R  |  12.00   |  4/1/13 B  |   250   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 2   | Jeff  |  100  | 1/1/13 R  |  15.00   |  1/1/13 B  |   500   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 2   | Jeff  |  100  | 2/1/13 R  |  15.00   |  2/1/13 B  |   400   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 2   | Jeff  |  100  | 3/1/13 R  |  15.00   |  3/1/13 B  |   500   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 2   | Jeff  |  100  | 4/1/13 R  |  15.00   |  4/1/13 B  |   500   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I'm looking to get is this:

```
ID   | Name  | Dept  |  1/1/13 R  |  1/1/13 B |  2/1/13 R  |  2/1/13 B | etc..
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1   | John  | 100   |   10.00    |    200    |    10.50   |    220    | etc..
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1   | Jeff  | 100   |   15.00    |    500    |    15.00   |    400    | etc..
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to basically get one line per employee with what their rate and bonus for a given pay period. I'm dynamically creating the columns, so the code I'm currently using is as follows:

```
DECLARE @columns1 VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @columns2 VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @columns1 = COALESCE (
            @columns1 + ',[' + CAST(BonusDate as VARCHAR) + ']',
            '[' + CAST(BonusDate as VARCHAR) + ']'
        )
FROM
    #tmptable1
GROUP BY
    BonusDate
ORDER BY
    BonusDate

SELECT @columns2 = COALESCE (
            @columns2 + ',[' + CAST(RateDate as VARCHAR) + ']',
            '[' + CAST(RateDate as VARCHAR) + ']'
        )
FROM
    #tmptable1
GROUP BY
    RateyDate
ORDER BY
    RateDate

SET @query = '
SELECT
    ID
    ,Name
    ,Dept
    ,' + @columns1 + '
    ,' + @columns2 + '
FROM (
    SELECT
        ID
        ,Name
        ,Dept
        ,HrRate
        ,RateDate
        ,Bonus
        ,BonusDate
    FROM
        #tmptable1
    ) as x
PIVOT (
    SUM(Bonus)
    FOR BonusDate
        IN(' + @columns1 + ')
)
AS p1
PIVOT (
    SUM(HrRate)
    FOR RateDate
        IN(' + @columns2 + ')
)
AS p2
'
```

EXECUTE ( @query )

This gives me one line for each date (RateDate and BonusDate). So, I'm almost there.

Props to http://www.tsqltutorials.com/ for the dynamic column creation pivot script too!

Comment: Can you post what you want for the final result?  How do you determine which `HrRate` to display since you have multiple values for some employees?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I ultimately do want to show what the employee's rate was at the time the bonus was paid. In essence there will most likely need to be two columns for each date: one showing the bonus amount and one showing the hourly rate.

Comment: I made some changes to the original question. I'm a bit new to stackoverflow (long time lurker), so I hope that's the correct way to go about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Sql..

HRRate have different value for employee John so that why it giving you multiple rows for John

```
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @columns = COALESCE (
            @columns + ',[' + CAST(PayDate as VARCHAR) + ']',
            '[' + CAST(PayDate as VARCHAR) + ']'
        )
FROM
    #tmptable1
GROUP BY
    PayDate
ORDER BY
    PayDate

set @query = 'SELECT id,name,dept, ' + @columns + ' from 
        (
            select id,name,dept
                , Bonus
                , PayDate
            from #tmptable1
       ) x           

        pivot 
        (
           SUM(Bonus)
            for PayDate in (' + @columns + ')
        ) p1 '

EXECUTE ( @query )
```

Comment: Thanks for the code :-) In the comment to bluefeet, I clarify that I actually want to show what hourly rate was paid at the time the bonus was paid. I'll end up with two columns for each individual date: one showing the hourly rate and one showing the bonus paid.